# Import Bootstrap 3 in Meteor 1.3

Tags: meteor

There aren't many imports that I can do when converting my app to 1.3, but one of them would be an import of Bootstrap 3, to replace the **twbs:bootstrap** wrapper.

However I see that ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3, which I find very convenient, depends on the twbs:bootstrap package.

Has anyone got any advice on what to do here?

Comment: It seems that the whole thing should be implemented using `npm`, no need to wait for the package update: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37333520/3436166

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package author should fix that in an upcoming release.

Meanwhile, you can clone the ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 package repo in your `packages` project folder and edit the dependency in the `package.js` file. 
Once you have done that, remove it and add it from and to your project. You will then use the local version (with no dependence) instead of the online one.

Step by step, it means:

1. In your console, when in the project folder `mkdir packages`, then `cd packages`
2. `git clone git@github.com:ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.git`
3. In the package folder, open `package.js` and remove the following lines:

   ```
   // Allows the user of this package to choose their own Bootstrap
   // implementation.
   api.use(['twbs:bootstrap@3.3.1',
            'nemo64:bootstrap@3.3.1_1'],
            'client', {weak: true});
   ```
4. save `the package.js` file and go back to your console. Go back to your project main folder and type `meteor remove ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` and `meteor add ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3`

Et voilà

Comment: Yes, I reckon the package author is the only one who can deal with this. Cloning the package is too much work

Comment: It really isn't too much work. Have a look, I edited my answer to detail the steps. I think that should be all what you need to do.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, but what I actually meant was that right now I don't need it that urgently. However the steps you have given will probably be useful to others.